# On hover color of help menu links is difficult to distinguish

Tags: bug, design, top-bar, help-center

Could we change text link color when hovering over help menu items?
The color used at the moment seems too similar.

> [image]

As you can see in the image above, you can't easily see if you're hovering over an item or not. The color used is too similar to the normal link color.

Comment: Can you explain the issue a bit more? You may have a valid point but without more info it's hard to tell. What 'help menu item' do you refer to? Can you attach a screenshot so we can see what you're referring to. Or at least provide a link to the relevant page you're concerned with.

Comment: The hover color is the same for all top bar links and I agree, a little hard to notice - especially on the inbox and help menu.

Answer (score -1):

i suggest,
if we can make the hover to be gray on the box container of text link like on Google gmail on top menu like more, settings menu when menu list and you hover on any item you see the box container of menu item become gray.

i think this is good ui than current